# Load the value of an entity field type in another form

Tags: entities, configuration, plugins

I have created a custom field and I wish to load the value dynamically in another form in relation to the specific node entity the value belongs to.
I understand that to get the value I have to use/know the field_name like this

```
$entity->get('field_name')->getValue();
```

What I want is to get the field_name set via content configurations with only the type of node and the field name as defined in the fieldItem Plugin

```
$field_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions('node');
```

When I dump $field_definitions am able to see all the fields array with all the details but I can't get my node.field_name in relation to the fieldItem name defined in the specific field plugin, in my case field_custom_example

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_custom_example' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "field_custom_example",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom Example"),
 *   description = @Translation("Stores data for Custom Example Field"),
 *   default_widget = "custom_example_widget",
 *   default_formatter = "custome_example_formatter"
 * )
 */
```

that's where am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method [FieldDefinitionInterface::getType](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldDefinitionInterface.php/function/FieldDefinitionInterface%3A%3AgetType/8.6.x):

> Returns the field type.
>
> **Return value**
>
> (string) The field type, i.e. the id of a field type
>   plugin. For example 'text'.

In your case for example:

```
foreach ($field_definitions as $name => $definition) {
  if ($definition->getType() == 'field_custom_example') {
    // found field $name
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for pointing me that way..I could upvote the answer..but unfortunately am not qualified yet..am grateful.